# Difficulties in modelling magnetic levitation system?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, inductance, levitation

I'm currently working on a project surrounding magnetic levitation with an electromagnet having to levitate an object underneath itself. I have taken a look at research papers, examined their calculations and have basically taken "inspiration" from their works to apply to my calculations, such as the modelling of the mechanical and electrical. However, midway through calculations, I noticed that I could not obtain one of the values, yet all the authors somehow come up with random values assigned to this "constant" that was more or less left undefined.

This constant, C = L0x0/2 which is calculated from doing a derivative as [shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0LUs.png) has its value already obtained, being given as a [Newton-Meter^2/Area squared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gUz4h.png).

[But I do not understand how they even assigned it to them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQDGq.png). Just when I had the calculations almost complete, this came out of the left field and just confused me completely. What am I supposed to do? How do I determine C's value?

Papers:

https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=7169988 https://addi.ehu.es/bitstream/handle/10810/36694/MasterThesis.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=8986710 https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=5570565 [https://www.slideshare.net/SalimAlOufi/mse6183finalprojectwriteupslso05052015rev2#:~:text=This%20project%20is%20about%20controlling%20the%20position%20of,feedback%20of%20the%20position%20of%20the%20magnetic%20ball.?msclkid=ed73953da6fd11eca322287678e98ddb](https://www.slideshare.net/SalimAlOufi/mse6183finalprojectwriteupslso05052015rev2#:%7E:text=This%20project%20is%20about%20controlling%20the%20position%20of,feedback%20of%20the%20position%20of%20the%20magnetic%20ball.?msclkid=ed73953da6fd11eca322287678e98ddb)

Comment: Did you look in references 13 & 14 of the Larrañaga paper?  It seems like they're saying that further information can be found there.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question [How do i mathematically model a magnetic levitation system? Having difficulties figuring out the necessary parts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/699871/how-do-i-mathematically-model-a-magnetic-levitation-system-having-difficulties)

Comment: Not a duplicate, because I have modelled my system and I am struggling with understanding how these authors have obtained a value for a magnetic constant that was not even explained thoroughly. I am genuinely confused and need help, I have researched all over the net and find conflicting opinions on this, I am failing to understand why these authors have to make these things so sophisticated, why not just explain stuff on the paper and make it easier for the future gen??? It also does not help having my post taken down before reading through its contents because it is definitely not a clone.